# How to figure out whether existing DSL modem can connect to my ~50 Mbit/s internet connection?

Tags: internet, wireless-router, isp, adsl-router, dsl-modem

Some month ago I switch from a 16 MBit/s to a 50 MBit/s internet connection and started renting a AVM FRITZ!Box 7412 which is extremely buggy in term of the web UI (random appearance of elements) and port forwarding (random functioning). I exchanged several emails with the AVM support and they understand the problem, but they want me to do intensive debugging work for them. Furthermore, since it's not FLOSS, the work to fix issues will become useless over time.

I had several other AVM "wifi routers" before which also all had trouble doing their job so that I replaced them with a "wifi router" from a previous DSL contract. However, connecting one now causes no connection to be established and the feedback of the routers is all not useful at first sight. Before diving into extensive investigation and more work hours, I'd like to make sure that there's a change that any of the "wifi routers" fit to the 50 MBit/s connection at all.

As of January 2016 ISP are forced by law to accept any DSL modem to connect on the client side in Germany. However that wouldn't apply if it wasn't technically possible with the devices I have at hand. What do I have to watch out for when connecting the "old" "wifi routers"?

The provider is 1und1 Internet AG and the connection is in Berlin, Germany.

Comment: Although the question contains a hint about my location the question would still make sense if I'd take them out, so it's not too localized imo.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need a modem that supports VDSL2, as 50Mbps is near the limit of original VDSL and you have to be very close to the DSLAM to get that rate. These speeds are far above the range that ADSL2+ could be expected to provide, even with two modems.